# Mysql Count more Categorie IDs and connect db page in other page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want count more as one Categorie ID in my Laravel PHP page.

Now my code with one Categorie ID:

```
SELECT category_id FROM products WHERE category_id = 1
```

How can i select category_id= 1 + 2 or more, not only 1?

i have two Products in Categorie ID 1 and one Product in Categorie ID 2 and result must be "3"

Other Question, i want use an other page for my Mysql DB connection.
Example: My Count Code is in index Laravel page but my connect.blade.php in other folder and include it in index page.

I have try some options but Laravel shows an error.

Index:

```
@include('connect')

    <?php

    $sql="SELECT category_id FROM products WHERE category_id = 1 ";

    if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      // Return the number of rows in result set
      $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
      printf("%d\n",$rowcount);
      // Free result set
      mysqli_free_result($result);
      }

    ?>
```

the connect.blade.php file is located in laravel "views" folder and index.blade.php in "view/master". I get always the Error "Undefined variable: con", whats the Problem?

connect.blade.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You know, there're controllers in laravel, that can do all the stuff?

Comment: You mean for Mysql Connection that i dont need an connection file? Yes but i am a beginner in Laravel and thats the only method that works for me now.

Comment: Please find a simple laravel tutorial and follow it. What you do now is a nonsense.

Comment: okay thanks for the info, i have read many simple tutorials and dont work for me because all write it other and now i am confused...

Comment: Can you explain please what is nonsense from my code?

Comment: Laravel follows MVC architecture of an application. Read what is __MVC__ and understand what is a view and what should be in it. Laravel already has tools to make queries to databases. There's no need to create connections, laravel __does__ this for you. These are main topics.

Comment: Many Thanks, helped me a lot to learn more! I search and read more about it:)